# What is the impact of overlooking learning scales?

Tags: scales, classical-guitar

I've been playing guitar for about a month. I know that learning scales is so important, but I just hate learning them. My question is what is the impact of not learning scales from the beginning in the long term?

Answer (score 4):

Scales teach your fingers where to find notes on the neck, and your brain how to think about intervals.

Without scales you will find it much harder to move around the fretboard, both on a single string, up and down the neck, but also across the neck. This will impact speed, clarity, and also your own composition processes.

I would say it is essential to learn scales, and then modes, in all positions and on all strings, so that you aren't limited when it comes to playing.

Put in the effort - it will benefit you in future!

Answer (score 3):

**Scales are absolutely vital, but only for their usefulness and their applicability.** If you hate learning them, maybe your approach to learning them needs to be more musical. If you are just trying to learn the scale patterns all up and down the fretboard, you're missing the point. Granted, knowing your fretboard geometry is important too. However, if you can't apply a scale in one position, why learn all the other positions for that scale? If I gave you one position of a nonsense scale and it sounded terrible, unless you're into some avant-garde harmony or something, you won't see any reason to keep learning that scale.

So musical application is key. If you can, get a loop pedal or find some jam tracks on youtube. For a new scale, get just enough information to be able to play it and get a common position. Then jump right in. All the more in depth learning can wait for when you're interested in getting more info. Understand with your ears first. Everything else will fall into place. Find what notes fit on certain chords and learn how to navigate in a basic sense. For example, if you want to learn the Dorian scale, a common key is D. So learn the D Dorian scale in fifth position:

```
e|-----------------------5-7-8-7-5-----------------------|
b|-----------------5-6-8-----------8-6-5-----------------|
G|-----------4-5-7-----------------------7-5-4-----------|
D|-------5-7-----------------------------------7-5-------|
A|-5-7-8-------------------------------------------8-7-5-|
E|-------------------------------------------------------|
```

Then find a jam track for D Dorian or play Dm<sup>7</sup> - G<sup>7</sup> on your looper and with just that one position, you can do wonders. Then, when or if you're into it, learn more positions, find players who use the scale well, learn solo, transcribe solos, etc. Whatever you feel motivated to do to delve deeper into the scale.

The wonderful thing about music is that a lot of the ideas have been around for hundred of years, if not longer, but there's always more to learn and more to play and more to do. Learning scales is just one window into the musical minds of the greats that have come before us and just one way to develop our own musical understanding. Especially for guitar, learning scales is learning musical patterns and exploring scales is to explore these patterns. If you're not interested in learning scales, don't sweat it. You're not alone. They can be boring. But if you're serious about learning music and improving your playing, scales are essential.

Answer (score 2):

It's not important to learn scales, *if* you can think of a better way to...

- choose which notes to play when you're improvising
- remember which notes to play in the songs you're playing
- understand what people are talking about when they are talking about scales with commonly-used terminology.

So, can you?

Well, for the first two, it's certainly possible that you don't have to have your head in a scales mindset all that time. When it comes to choosing what notes to play, none of the common scales represent any kind of theoretical *starting point* from a physics / psychoacoustics point of view.

When it comes to memorising pieces too, I often remember pieces more by patterns and muscle memory. What note of the scale I'm playing is something I could also tell you straight away, and I might use that knowledge to help me improvise, but it's not what I'm really using to remember how to play the piece.

When it comes to communication with others, and understanding what people are talking about, you'll be up a creek without the terminology if you've not learned it, obviously.

Don't make too much of a big deal about it! As long as you find a smart way to learn scales, it won't take you a lot of time and you will be learning a lot of things that you will find helpful to navigate the fretboard however you're thinking about the notes you are playing. Just learn them at least to the point where you know what they are, then when you need them in the future, you'll know what it is that you need!

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, a tune is played in one key. To learn that tune, one has to find each and every note by randomly looking for it, then on to the next, etc.Some of the notes played while trying to find the right ones won't ever be in that tune, as they don't feature in that key. Basically, in, say, a major key, there will be 7 notes that will probably feature, thus 5 more that rarely will. That's a lot of room for error, using hit-and-miss.

Knowing the notes that WILL feature saves a lot of time and effort. So, if you know that set of notes, often called a scale, it'll cut out a load of fuss.Most middle of the road tunes are based on full major or full minor scale notes, so once one knows some scale patterns, one can get to predict what the next note in a tune will be far better than randomly picking out possible notes. Working from the dots, one will 'lock in' to the set of notes used in a piece if one knows that scale.

When you come to compose your own pieces, knowing which notes work together will help. Use the notes from a particular scale, and you're there. Maybe start with the pentatonics, which bridge the gap between arpeggios and full scales, and tunes start to flow easily. Especially on guitar, which is tuned in such a way as to make pentatonics easy to find, use and play.